# Unable to get query parameters from laravel url get request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

this is my url and i am unable to get the query parameters i dont know why.
anyone can tell me whats going on?

```
http://localhost:8000/senders/verify#/activate?user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated
```

if I use

```
http://localhost:8000/senders/verify?user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated
```

I can successfully get the varaibles but after putting #/activate i can't. i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value after the **hash mark** (`#`) as shown in a user's browser: This isn't possible with "`standard`" **HTTP** as this value is never sent to the server (hence it won't be available in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or similar predefined variables). You would need some sort of JavaScript magic on the client side, e.g. to include this value as a POST parameter.

So when you call :

```
localhost:8000/senders/verify#/activate?user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated
```

Your server get this :

```
localhost:8000/senders/verify
```

The browser delete everything from the **hash** (`#`) of your url, then it pass to the server http process

Comment: i cant do that because this comes from a source.. i cant change the url structure i just need the user parameter in laravel thats it...

Comment: @Qaisar, hope I clarify you

Answer (score 0):

Because paths are not the same. So your route file cannot run from same line.
for this

```
http://localhost:8000/senders/verify#/activate?user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated
```

First part => senders

Second part => verify#

Third part => activate

And these are the params => user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated

For this one:

```
http://localhost:8000/senders/verify? user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated
```

First part => senders

Second part => verify

Params => user=qaisar72477247@email.com&option=AccountActivated

didnt have the third part.

Comment: i cant do that because this comes from a source.. i cant change the url structure i just need the user parameter in laravel thats it...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the order of the URL. The `#` is an anchor or fragment component, and is the last part of the URL. The query string should come before the fragment component, as anything after that will be ignored.

```
scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
```

[src: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)

I'm guessing you're using some sort of framework such as Vue, Angular, or React, which means anything after the `#` is actually handled by that, and is not passed to Laravel. You'll need to manage the request with whichever framework you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but i cannot change it... This is the redirect from a web resource i cannot change there url structure thats the reason